# Kafka не линкуется через CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake, apache-kafka

Не могу понять как прилинковать lrdkafka++ библиотеку через Cmake.

Установил на Debian 12.0 пакет кафки
$ apt install librdkafka-dev

Header находится по адресу

```
#/usr/include/librdkafka/rdkafkacpp.h
```

В описании сказано линковать программу с `lrdkafka++ (C++).`

Поиском нашел файлы самой библиотеки

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытаюсь использовать `RdKafka::Conf`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstring>

#if _AIX
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <librdkafka/rdkafkacpp.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace RdKafka;



int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    RdKafka::Conf *conf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_GLOBAL);

}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(kafka_Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include_directories(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)

find_package(rdkafka++)

add_executable(kafka_Test main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC rdkafka++)
```

find_package не находит rdkafka++ или я что то делаю не так?

Comment: Что даст команда `pkg-conf --libs rdkafka++`?

Comment: выдает: -lrdkafka++

Comment: `find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(rdkafka++ REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET rdkafka++)

add_executable(kafka_Test main.cpp
        KafkaProducer/KafkaProducer.h)

target_link_libraries(kafka_Test PUBLIC PkgConfig::rdkafka++)` Такой код сработал, но я не понял механизм добавления таких библиотек где есть header и уже собранная dll

Comment: А то что у него нет find файлов для cmake, поэтому используется pkg-conf

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста как понять что нету find файлов и нужно использовать pkg-conf? и как понять какие библиотеки есть в  pkg-conf?

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.27/command/find_package.html